# How can I call a asyncThunk action of redux-toolkit inside a getServerSideProps of nextJs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk, next.js13

I am using nextJs 13 and redux-toolkit and i am fetching my data with AsyncThunk .
Now, I want to get my data with getServerSideProps inside my UI component at the first render.
I tried to use the next wrapper, but the action is not being called at all .
NOTE : the action is called when i dispatch it inside useEffect , but nothing happend when

[image: This is my thunk action inside the slice]

[image: This is my wrapper inside the store]

[image: This is my getServerSideProps function inside my component]

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with NextJS, but here are my 5 cents...

[unwrap](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#unwrapping-result-actions) can help you get the final results of an asyncThunk.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps (context) {
  const rooms = await store.dispatch(getAllRooms()).unwrap();
  return { props: { rooms } }
}
```

Also in the `catch` part of `getAllRooms`, you should use [rejectWithValue](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-errors)

```js
export const getAllRooms = createAsyncThunk('rooms/fetchRooms', async (payload, thunkAPI) => {
  try {
    ...
  } catch (err) {
    return thunkAPI.rejectWithError(err.message)
  }
})
```

> I want to get my data with getServerSideProps inside my UI component at the first render

In order to solve that, you can `return null` inside your component if the data "is not there" (meaning that the promise/thunk is not fulfilled). This way your component will render only when the needed data is present, meaning also that it will already have the data on first render.

```
export const RoomsScreen = ({ rooms }) => {
  if (!rooms) {
    return null
  }

  return <div>the list of my rooms: {rooms.toString()}</div>
}
```